# Caffe's way of representing negative examples on benchmark dataset for binary classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I would like to know how to define or represent a negative training set if I would want to train a binary classifier from a pre-trained model say, AlexNet on ILSVRC12 (or ImageNet) dataset. What I am currently thinking of is to take one the classes which is not related as the negative training set while the one which is related as positive one. Is there any better way which is more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CNNs trained on the ILSVRC data set are already discriminating among 1000 classes of images.  Yes, you can use one of those topologies to train a binary classifier, but I suggest that you start with an untrained model and run it through your two chosen classes.  If you start with a trained model, you have to *unlearn* a lot, and your result is still trying to discriminate among 1000 classes: that last FC layer is going to give you trouble.

There are ways to work around the 1000-class problem.  If your application already overlaps one or more of the trained classes, then simply add a layer that maps those classes to label "1" and all the others to label "0".

If you're insistent on retaining the trained kernels, then try replacing the final FC layer (1000) with a 2-class FC layer.  Then choose your two classes (applicable images vs everything else) and run your training.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But, do you mean the one that you mentioned in the 2nd paragraph is the same as the 3rd? If so, do you have any snippet that show what you meant by "then simply add a layer that maps those classes to label "1" and all the others to label "0"."?

Comment: I did what you mentioned in the 3rd para by changing 1000 to 2 in the FC layer, and train on my own data but the prediction accuracy is rather low i.e. about 55%. I am interested in what you mentioned "then simply add a layer that maps those classes to label "1" and all the others to label "0".", how do I implement this at prototxt level?

Comment: And yes, my application overlaps with one of the train classes.

Comment: 2nd paragraph: The mapping layer would be a new layer type, hard-coded for the applicable class labels.  If you're not comfortable adding a layer type of your own, then skip that and go for the training idea.

Comment: Do you have any pointer (URLs perhaps) on what you meant? I know it's about adding a layer in the prototxt file, but implementation-wise, I'm still clueless. I've done the training idea, but the result is poor and that's why I want to explore the 2nd paragraph that you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Just search for a tutorial on Caffe and adding layers.  I'm afraid that my materials for this activity are all in-house examples.